# Theorem 9.9 - Tu's "An Introduction To Manifolds"

Tags: notation, proof-explanation, manifolds

Just a trouble understanding the notation in the proof.

> Let $F : N \to M$ be a $C^{\infty}$ map of manifolds, with $\text{dim} \; N = n$ and $\text{dim} \; M = m$. Then a nonempty regular level set $F^{-1}(c)$ where $c \in M$, is a regular submanifold of $N$ of dimension equal to $n - m$
>
> Proof: Choose a chart $(V,\psi) = (V,y^1,\ldots,y^m)$ of $M$ centered at $c$, i.e. such that $\psi(c) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $F^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $N$ that contains $F^{-1}(c)$ is the zero set of $\psi \circ F$. If $F^i = y^i \circ F = r^i \circ (\psi \circ F)$, then $F^{-1}(c)$ is also the common zero set of the functions $F^1,\ldots,F^m$ on $F^{-1}(V)$. Because the regular level set is assumed nonempty, $n \geq m$. Fix a point $p \in F^{-1}(c)$ and let $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ be a coordinate neighborhood of $p$ in $N$ contained in $F^{-1}(V)$. Since $F^{-1}(c)$ is a regular level set, $p \in F^{-1}(c)$ is a regular point of $F$. Therefore, the $m \times n$ Jacobian matrix $\left[ \partial F^i/\partial x^j(p) \right]$ has rank $m$. By renumbering the $F^i$ and $x^j$'s we may assume the first $m \times m$ block $\left[ \partial F^i / \partial x^j (p)\right]_{1 \leq i, j\leq m}$ is non singular. Replace the first $m$ coordinates $x^1,\ldots,x^m$ of the chart $(U,\phi)$ by $F^1,\ldots,F^m$. We claim that there's a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ such that $(U_p,F^1,\ldots,F^m,x^{m+1},\ldots,x^n)$ is a chart in the atlas of $N$. It suffices to compute it's Jacobian matrix at $p$:
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j} & \frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^\beta} \\
> \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^j} & \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^\beta}
> \end{bmatrix} =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j} & * \\
> 0 & I
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> where $1 \leq i, j \leq m$ and $m + 1 \leq \alpha, \beta \leq n$
> Since this matrix has determinant
> $$
> \text{det} \left[ \frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}(p)\right]_{1 \leq i,j \leq m} \neq 0
> $$
> The inverse function theorem in the form of Corollary 6.27 implies the claim.

First of all why we replace the first $m$ coordinates with the components of $F$, what exactly do we end up having? Also the jacobian notation is a bit weird, it seems to me that it's a 2x2 matrix, but then I see the $I$ (identity matrix) as a subblock.

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: In the matrix that you are seeing as a $2\times 2$ matrix put brackets around each entry and as subscripts to the brackets the inequalities $1\leq i,j\leq m$ and $m+1\leq\alpha,\beta\leq n$ as they did in the line that follows. It looks like they used the notation $[a_{i,j}]_{r\leq i,j\leq s}$ for a matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$ with $i,j$ ranging between $r$ and $s$, in the last equation, but skipped cluttering the previous formula with the same notation.

Comment: The point is, the $F^i,x^{n-i}$ give you a slice chart in the manifold $M$. I think Tu calls them "adapted charts". Then you apply a theorem which says that in the presence of slice charts, the level sets can be  given the structure of a (sub)manifold.